# Cannot keep jQuery dropdown slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

So I'm making a website for someone and I'm quite new to jQuery (which probably doesn't help). The site needed a dropdown menu to display links to the galleries in a list rather than having them all in the navigation bar. The problem is, whenever I hover over the li element the dropdown slides down but when I hover over the dropdown, it slides back up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("li#navi-dropdown").hover(
    function () {
      $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideDown('medium');
    }, 
    function () {
      $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideUp('medium');
    }
  );
});
```

Probably something simple, but help is quite welcome. JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/6e87Lwkb/

Comment: Why don't you use a front end framework rather than using plain html,css,and jquery?

Comment: http://codepen.io/firnasfaris10/pen/PZPVgG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting your ul submenu inside your li, and reposition it.
Don't forget to use .stop() too, so as jquery don't queue your slides animations :

```
$('ul.nav-dropdown').stop().slideDown('medium');
```

[See your updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6e87Lwkb/3/%20%22See%20your%20updated%20fiddle)

Comment: Unlike the others, if you don;t hover over the dropdown and just take your mouse off of the gallery button, the dropdown still disappears which is what I want. Thank you all for your responses, but this one seems to be the most complete.

Answer (score 2):

You are toggeling the event in the me handler, you need to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("li#navi-dropdown").on('mouseover',function () {
     $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideDown('medium');
  })

  $("ul.nav-dropdown").on('mouseleave',function () {
     $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideUp('medium');
  });
});
```

I have also updated your fiddle, check it out it works now.

here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e87Lwkb/7/

Comment: @Mohamed I really don't understand your comment (and the eventually down vote) did you check the fiddle? I think this is what the OP was asking for he say:  'The problem is, whenever I hover over the li element the dropdown slides down but when I hover over the dropdown, it slides back up.', and that is just what I did. I have changed also his own fiddle in where he was just toggeling th event, that's why you are thinking that my answer is not correct.

Comment: @Mohamed Maybe is not a good practice to change the original OP fiddle. Man keeps learning in here, When I will post an answer I wont do it anymore. Thank for updating your comment. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li#navi-dropdown").hover(
  function () {
     $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideDown('medium');
  });
  $(".nav-dropdown").mouseleave(
  function () {
     $('ul.nav-dropdown').slideUp('medium');
  });
});
```